# Ruby on Rails - Nested attributes not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have this two simple models:

```
class Address < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :community

  geocoded_by :full_address

  validates :address, :city, :province, :country, presence: :true

  validates :postalcode, presence: true, postalcode: true

  after_validation :geocode

  def full_address
    [address, province, postalcode, country].compact.join(', ')
  end
end
```

And

```
class Community < ApplicationRecord
  has_one :address, dependent: :destroy

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :address

  has_many :community_people, dependent: :destroy

  has_many :people, through: :community_people, source: :user

  validates :name, :address, :administrators, presence: true  
  # ...
end
```

I'm trying to create some stub Communities using a seed.rb:

```
def self.create_community(administrators: [], residents: [], address: {})
     Community.create(
        name:  Faker::Name.name,
        administrators: administrators,
        residents: residents,
        address_attributes: address
      )

    @communities += 1
  end
```

But I always get:

```
ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid: Validation failed: Address community must exist
```

PS: Also tried using "community.create_address" and other things.
To only way I could get it to work was:

- Saving Community (with no address)
- Saving Address referencing community_id.

But I had to hack my Model and remove `:address` from the `validates` method in **community.rb**.

So how can I make **accepts_nested_attributes_for** work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are using Rails 5. This issue is because of feature change in Rails 5. For more info [read this](http://blog.bigbinary.com/2016/02/15/rails-5-makes-belong-to-association-required-by-default.html).
You should try adding `optional: true` to `belongs_to` relationship. Like this.

```
class Address < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :community, optional: true
end
```

Comment: Even though I cant have an Address without a Community?